# apt-get -u dist-upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, консоль, apt-get, kali-linux

Что делает эта команда и что значит `-u`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dist-upgrade` в дополнение к выполнению функции обновления, также обновляет пакеты зависимостей

Параметр `-u` показывает список обновленных пакетов

Подробнее о команде `apt-get` Вы можете узнать на странице руководства `man` или здесь: https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы узнать о командах, прочитайте страницу руководства (короткая "manpage") с помощью команды `man`.
Например, чтобы узнать о `apt-get`, введите следующую команду:

```
man apt-get
```

`dist-upgrade`
        в дополнение к выполнению функции обновления,
        также разумно обрабатывает изменения зависимостей с новыми версиями
        пакетов;
`apt-get` имеет "умную" систему разрешения конфликтов и она будет в случае необходимости пытаться произвести обновление наиболее важных пакетов за счет менее важных.
  Файл `/etc/apt/sources.list` содержит список источников для получения пакетов, из которых будут получены файлы пакетов.

---

Опция `-u`, в данном случае, выдает список всех пакетов, которые были обновлены.
`-u` её короткая запись, `--show-upgraded` длинная.

---

**Дополнительная литература на русском:**

[Часто задаваемые вопросы о Debian GNU/Linux](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/debian-faq.ru.pdf)
[Официальная документация Kali Linux](https://docs.kali.org/pdf/kali-book-ru.pdf)
[man apt-get (с оф. сайта Debian, на английском)](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt-get.8.en.html)

Answer (score 1):

`dist-upgrade` - это обновление ядра, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: не ошибаетесь!!! а что с -u ? что он делает ?